# How to use the "mover" command in Skak

Tags: errors, chess, skak

I teach after school chess, and installed LaTeX on my computer just to make chess worksheets. I'm using `skak`.

My documents start:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chess-workshop-symbols}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
```

and then have the problems I want to give the kids, like so:

```
% one solution, three checks
\fenboard{5rk1/pp3N1p/4P3/2P5/3Q1PK1/P7/1Pr3pq/R3R3 w - - 0 0}
\showboard
```

I would love to have the worksheets show whether it is black's move or white, but I haven't been able to get the command 
`\showmoverOn` to work (nor `\showmover` or `\moverOn` or `\mover`). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

When I try it, the console output says something like:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ShowMoverBlackNormal ->\pscustom 
                                  [fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]{\skak@tra...
l.23 \showboard

?
```

Answer (score 4):

As kahen wrote, `skak` relies on `pstricks` for some of the "decoration". I suggest to use `chessboard` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}
\chessboard[setfen=5rk1/pp3N1p/4P3/2P5/3Q1PK1/P7/1Pr3pq/R3R3 w - - 0 0,
            showmover]
\end{document}
```

If you want to print/parse moves you can use either `skak` or `xskak`, both will work together with `chessboard`. You don't need `chess-workshop-symbols`: the symbols it defines are nowadays defined by the `chessfss` package used internally from all the three packages.

Answer (score 2):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that you're trying to compile your document with `pdflatex`. `skak` makes use of `pstricks` for drawing things, so you'll either need `auto-pst-pdf` or just compile with `latex`.

Comment: Could also use [`xskak`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak), which should support PDF natively.

Comment: You need to load `skak` with the option `ps` (`\usepackage[ps]{skak}`) in order for this to work properly.

Comment: When using xskak, the mover command does not work. When compiling via latexila, the error: Undefined control sequence is shown.